# Log only what I print in Xcode

Tags: ios, xcode

While building an iOS app in Xcode, how do I set the log to show only what I print()?

I am wasting a huge amount of time sifting through garbage that looks like this

> 2016-10-18 06:26:49.455995 Lunch[1559:32097] subsystem: com.apple.UIKit, category: HIDEventFiltered, enable_level: 0, persist_level: 0, default_ttl: 0, info_ttl: 0, debug_ttl: 0, generate_symptoms: 0, enable_oversize: 1, privacy_setting: 2, enable_private_data: 0
>   2016-10-18 06:26:49.458682 Lunch[1559:32097] subsystem: com.apple.UIKit, category:

I end up using hacks like `print("SEARCHFORME")` so I can use the find command and search for messages I need while debugging.

Comment: Since Xcode 8.1 this is now off by default

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Go to -> [image]

Edit Scheme -> Run -> Environment Variables -> set Name to - OS_ACTIVITY_MODE and Value to - disable.

[image]