# iOS app print statements - how to view

Tags: ios, xcode, debugging, adb

I would like to view the console output of a published app running on USB attached iOS device, like adb for Android.

(I do NOT want to view the iOS operating system output, which is what you can see in the xCode device window, or using deviceconsole)

I just want the stdout of the app - just like adb for Android.

Is this possible?

Comment: Clarification - it is a published app.

Answer (score 0):

[image: XCode screen]

Below the console you can change the output shown in the console you can [see the documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/DeveloperTools/Conceptual/debugging_with_xcode/chapters/debugging_tools.html)

> Output control. You specify the type of output the console displays with the pop-up menu in the lower-left corner of the console pane:

- All Output displays target and debugger output.
- Debugger Output displays debugger output only.
- Target Output displays target output only.

Also you can see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40107102/log-only-what-i-print-in-xcode)

Comment: It is a published app from the app store.